# Font family and font weight - very thick bold

Tags: css, fonts, typography

I have a collection of fonts. Let's say font-a-normal, font-a-italic, font-a-bold and so on with b, c...

If in some css file I have:

```
font-family: 'font-a-bold';
```

In another file, I could have

```
font-weight: bold;
```

The result actually is double bold font, that is two times thicker than what I need on some html pages. Because project specifications changed a lot over time and because I have a big  number of static pages that I would have to change manually if I would want only to remove **font-weight** I'm searching for another solution.

Is there a rule or some way to specify that 'font-a-bold' shouldn't become thicker. And if I have

```
font-family: 'font-a-normal';
font-weight: bold
```

it should actually become:

```
font-family:'font-a-bold'
```

Is there a pure css solution?

**Update**

Or a fast and possibly clean way of removing double bold.

Comment: Short answer: No. Had you written it in [sass](http://www.sass-lang.com) it would have been less tedious to modify.

Comment: So it's all webfonts, right?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz yes, we have home grown fonts that UX designers drew for web.

Comment: @PatsyIssa that isn't helpful. I have a project that is like this, no SASS, no CoffeeScript, poor design, no server that would build it dynamically and I have to deal with it. The only thing that I thout about is to make some scripts that would modify all files but now I'm searching for a clean way of doing it (if it exists). Otherwise - brute force, but this will require time.

Comment: How many font/font-weight declarations can there be? Go about them 1 by 1 and avoid the headache of a find/replace mess.

Comment: @PatsyIssa I have at least 60 css files. But luckily for me there are only 3 with font face declarations and are all global. Manually changing files is not very wise. If you can automate - you should do it. There are also scripts that change styles in the project at runtime... I think you got the picture.

Comment: ouch good luck man :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pulling in all the fonts with `@font-face` declarations, you probably could do something like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyFont-Bold';
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   src: ...
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyFont-Bold';
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
   src: ... // same as above: always the same bold
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyFont';
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   src: ... // regular weight new style
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyFont';
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   src: ... // boldweight new style
}
```

I would think the browser doesn't care if what you tell it is a bold weight is not actually any bolder than the regular.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1d85r0mo/)

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm actually searching for. It solves most of my problems. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell CSS to not apply a certain style if another style is being applied, So...

I would simply do this by using the 'lots of classes' approach to CSS.

Make classes:

```
.bold {
   font-family: 'font-a-bold';
}

.italic {
    font-family: 'font-a-italic';
}
```

and so on. Then just apply these classes to the text you want to have said font-family. Just don't apply a `<strong>` tag to a piece of text that is already using the `.bold` class for example.

Comment: Actually you can override styles but it's not a clean solution in my case.

Comment: Of corse you can override styles in CSS, you could use `!important` or chain selectors, or use an ID, or increase specificity of the selector by deeper nesting to name a few. But to write extendable and DRY CSS, I think using lots of classes like this is the best way to go, i'm not sure in what situation you would declare two rules in seperate CSS files, but then not want that outcome - just don't declare the font-weight twice. Maybe I have misunderstood your problem though. @inshador